# Sending push messages to all open chrome browsers via GCM

Tags: php, google-chrome, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to develop a web site which will send push notifications to all users currently watching it. I found some tutorials on how to send pushes to myself using GCM for Chrome and they are working fine,
(https://github.com/gauntface/simple-push-demo)
but I cannot understand how to send pushes to every user who is currently on my site and allowed to receive them. As far as I understand I need to collect their browser IDs when they subscribe

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration) {
serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({ userVisibleOnly: true })
  .then(onPushSubscription)
```

but I cannot find how to get and store them (perhaps in MySQL DB with PHP code) and after that how to send a push to everyone (probably to iterate over all browsers IDs in my DB and send pushes to everyone separately with cURL requests). On my site I have code which uses ServiceWorkers and handles users subscription but everything is working for me only. Noone who is else on a site does not receive any notifications. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you're right. Get and store IDs in your DB and after that iterate over all `browsers IDs` in my DB and send pushes to everyone separately with cURL requests. Or another way is `create a device group` or let your user to `subscribe` one topic and push the message to that topic.